# Design change to call constructors of 2 DTO classes

Tags: java

I have couple of DTO classes as below-

```
 class A{
    
    private Long id;
    private Long headerId;
    }

    class B{
    private Long id;
    private Long headerId;
    }
```

Another DTO class which extends one of the above class

```
class comparisonDTO extends B{
private Long id;

public comparisonDTO(A ADTO, B BDTO) {
        super(BDTO);
        //some op;
}
```

`comparisonDTO` constructor has been called as below in my `main` class-

```
BufferedList comparisonList = new BufferedList();
comparisonDTO compDTO = new comparisonDTO(ADTO, null);
comparisonList.add(compDTO);
```

Output- : `comparisonDTO[id = 1212, B=[id= ,headerId = ]]`

I want to add something like below in my list -

```
comparisonDTO[id: 1212, B:[id: ,headerId : ]]
comparisonDTO[id: 1213, A:[id: ,headerId : ]]
```

For this I guess will have to do something like calling DTO on condition. But I cannot do that since my comparisonDTO class is extending class B. super() would always call Class B constructor.

```
super(BDTO != null ? super(BDTO): super(ADTO);
```

Another thing I tried is putting reference of class A and B inside comparisonDTO class.

```
Class comparisonDTO{
private Long id;
private A AOBJ;
private B BOBJ;

public comparisonDTO(A ADTO, B BDTO) {
    populateData(BDTO);
        //super(BDTO);
        //some op;
}

pubic void populateData(BDTO){
    BOBJ = new B();
        if(BDTO != null) {
            BOBJ.setId(BDTO.getId());
            BOBJ.setHeaderId(BDTO.getHeaderId());
            }
        }
```

In this case, I get the comparisonList as (address reference of class) ;

```
comparisonDTO[id = 1212, com....comparisonDTO@42583fe6]
```

What should my design be to achive something as below?

```
comparisonDTO[id: 1212, B:[id: ,headerId : ]]
comparisonDTO[id: 1213, A:[id: ,headerId : ]]
```

Comment: First, to achieve an output like you describe you'd need to override the `toString()` method. Second, why exactly does `comparisonDTO` extend B? Btw, you should work on your naming, i.e. read up on the Java code conventions, and post code that at least looks like it might compile - `Class comparisonDTO extends class B` for sure won't.

Comment: Yeah .. I have changed.. I just wanted to create a scenario which could just explain my issue.

Comment: Well, your scenario doesn't explain why `comparisonDTO` extends `B` and still could be created without a `B` instance. Why not create a simple composite which _contains_ a reference to `A` and `B` like in your last snippet (just without the `extends B`) and populate the instances accordingly? Then override `toString()` to produce the output you want.

Comment: Yes. I will try this. Thanks.